# Java pass a getter function as paramter

Tags: java

I have some jobs running to start periodically some business process, but I want to be able to stop these jobs before their end without killing the thread to be able to finish some other process after.

So I have a boolean `isInterrupted` in my `JobRunner`, which is set at true when I want to interrupt the job.

My Job is calling a service method, and this method is basically a big `for each` (just to mention that this process should stay here and not be moved to the job). I want to stop this `for` when the `isInterrupted` variable is true.

Is there any way to pass this value by reference, or to pass a getter function as parameter as we could do in Javascript?

For information we are using in Java 8

Comment: Have a look into `Runnable`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html However, it is a bit unclear if you know the exact method that needs to be called why not simply create an interface and pass the interface to your job.

Comment: Am not sure if I understood your question right. What input would `isInterrupted()` method take? You could take a look at java 8's lambda expressions. (Supplier  / Function / Predicate)

Comment: Check out lambda expressions, :: (Method reference), and Command pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a `BooleanSupplier`.

```
class Finisher {
  private volatile boolean finished = false;
  public boolean isFinished() { return finished; }
}
class Runner {
  public void run(BooleanSupplier finishedSupplier) {
    while (!finishedSupplier.getAsBoolean()) {
      // do work
    }
  }

  public static void main() {
    Runner runner = new Runner()
    Finisher finisher = new Finisher();
    runner.run(finisher::isFinished);
  }
}
```

Of course, the finisher instance must somehow be able to update its `finished` flag. The code here is just for illustrative purposes to show how the syntax would be used.

`finisher::isFinished` is a method reference and is (more or less) equivalent to writing `() -> finisher.isFinished()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a reference to some external boolean that may change over time, there are two main ways to do it:

1. Pass an `AtomicBoolean`. Changes to its internal value in one thread can be seen in another thread.
2. Pass a `Supplier<Boolean>` to the child thread, which is effectively a metod reference to some method that returns a `Boolean`.

Edit: As pointed out by knittl, Java also has a `BooleanSupplier` that returns a `boolean` instead of a `Boolean`. In this case, that would presumably be preferable.